# Concise syntax to invoke instance methods after invoking LINQ methods

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have a type that wraps an `IEnumerable<T>` and contains some additional logic, implementing an interface which we'll call `IMyIterable<T>`. On one hand, I want people to use LINQ methods to filter and process `IMyIterable<T>` (by actually applying them to the underlying object), but on the other hand, I still want to fluently expose `IMyIterable<T>`'s custom *instance* functionality (e.g state information) after the LINQ methods have been applied. e.g.

```
var query = myIterable.Select(x => x.whatever);
//query is now of a completely different type than IMyIterable<T>
var result = query.MyCustomThingy(); 
//But I really want MyCustomThingy to work too.
```

I know a solution would be:

```
var query = myIterable.Linq(x => x.Select(y => y.Whatever));
```

But the extra brackets are unseemly to me. Are there any other ways I could do this? I'm not actually asking for the method `Select()` to return a custom class (though if there are neat ways to do this, e.g. involving code generation, I'm definitely aboard), just some neater syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is not tied to IEnumerable. You can implement the LINQ methods you need on IMyIterable itself (either as instance methods or as extension methods). This way you can even use the linq syntax directly on a variable of type IMyIterable.

E.g.:

```
public interface IMyIterable<T>
{
    IMyIterable<TOut> Select<TOut>(Func<T, TOut> selector);
    IMyIterable<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    // ...
}
```

This would allow you to write something like this:

```
 IMyIterable<T> source = ...;

 var query = from item in source 
             where item.X == Y
             select new {...}
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Still, though, I hope I can somehow avoid having to implement tons and tons of one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

Could you implement the methods on IMyIterable as extension methods to IEnumerable instead ? Not knowing exactly what this interface does makes it hard to come up with a solution.

Comment: That's not really possible. `IMyIterable<T>` has custom *instance* functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deriving from IEnumerable, you could create a bunch of equivalent methods on IMyIterable (returning IMyIterable) and forward them to the inner IEnumerable instance.

However this seems like a lot of work to go around a cast. I guess your suggested .Linq() solution would work OK.